# Code signing on multiple computers

Tags: xcode, code-signing, keychain

I use 2 machines for developing a Mac application. I just submitted my app to the app store from my desktop (generating and using the appropriate certificates from Apple for code signing).

I exported and installed the certificates on my laptop so that they show up in the keychain but, yet, I'm unable to build my app on my laptop because of the following error:

```
Check dependencies

[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity '3rd Party Mac Developer Application' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

Is there any way to use the same certificates for code signing on more than 1 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I use multiple computers and the same certificates all the time.

You need to also make sure you have the ***private*** keys imported into your keychains.

Comment: Thanks. I exported/imported "Distribution Signing Certificate" and that was enough to build on my laptop. I also got "Mac Installer Package" thinking I'll probably need it at a later phase.  
Did I miss anything?